# How to create submit button in PHP using HTML forms?

Tags: php, html, forms

Without this code my web page work fine...

```
echo "<form name="Patient" action="patient_history_display.php" method="get">";
    echo "<input type="submit" value="Click here to view patient history">";
echo "</form>";
```

However, after adding this part of code, I received two errors:

> ERROR 1:
>   SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
>   ERROR 2:
>   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: Because of incorrect quotes. Take a look at the syntax highlighting of your code here, it should help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not escaping quotes " although for echo you should start and close with single quote '

```
echo '<form name="Patient" action="patient_history_display.php" method="get">';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Click here to view patient history">';
echo '</form>';
```

and by escaping, I mean adding a backslash to the " inside the echo like so:

```
echo "<form name=\"Patient\" action=\"patient_history_display.php\" method=\"get\">";
echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Click here to view patient history\">";
echo "</form>";
```

as you can see, it's a hell of a lot easier to use quotes wisely!

or for big block stuff:

```
    echo <<<END
This uses the "here document" syntax to output
multiple lines with $variable interpolation. Note
that the here document terminator must appear on a
line with just a semicolon. no extra whitespace!
END;
```

https://www.php.net/echo

Comment: Just to add, you could alternatively use **one** `echo` statement instead of three :)

Comment: You can, including echo <<<End'ing. Updated :)

Comment: Well there's a couple of ways to go about it. You could either use [Heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), [break context](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php) or echo using [embedded newlines](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single). For large blocks of static HTML, I'd typically just break context.

Comment: I find I break context less and less these days, don't know why but hey ho

Answer (score 1):

Change the quotes from "" to ''.
    Try: `echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit">';`